# find the pattern and dynamically build regex to match the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

If asterisk * is present in the pattern, then it means a sequence of the same character of length 3 unless it is followed by {N} which represents how many characters should appear in the sequence where N will be at least 1. My goal is to determine if the second string exactly matches the pattern of the first string in the input. I'm having trouble building the Regex pattern

```
*{2}* mmRRR should return TRUE
*{2}* mRRR  should return FALSE
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82smw9zx/

## sample code::

```
pattern1 = /'queryStrSubStr.charAt(0){patternCount}'/;
var patternMatch = new RegExp(pattern1);
if(queryStrSubStr.match(patternMatch)) {
    result =  true;
} else result =  false;
```

Comment: Do you try to call JS in your pattern or it's part of pattern string?

Comment: Take a look at the [Regex Object Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) if you want to dynamically create patterns.

Comment: @Justinas -- https://jsfiddle.net/82smw9zx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `new RegExp()` to construct your regex pattern with variables (rather than attempting to include a variable directly in your regular expression literal).

You are trying to include variables `queryStrSubStr.charAt(0)` and `patternCount` in a regular expression literal like: `/'queryStrSubStr.charAt(0){patternCount}'/`, but JavaScript does not interpret those strings as variables inside the literal.

Following example demonstrates how to construct your regex pattern with variables as well as incorporating the html input from your fiddle so that you can test various patterns. Code comments explain how the code works.

```js
$('.btn').click(() => {
  const result = wildcards($('.enter_pattern').val());
  console.log(result);
});

const wildcards = (s) => {
  if (s.startsWith('*')) { // if input string starts with *
    let pattern;
    let [count, text] = s.split(' '); // split input string into count and text
    count = count.match(/\{\d+\}/); // match count pattern like {n}
    if (count) { // if there is a count
      pattern = new RegExp(text.charAt(0) + count); // regex: first character + matched count pattern 
    } else { // if there is no count   
      pattern = new RegExp(text.charAt(0) + '{3}'); // regex: first character + default pattern {3} 
    }
    
    return !!s.match(pattern); // return true if text matches pattern or false if not 
    
  } else { // if input string does not start with *  
    return 'No pattern';    
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="enter_pattern" />
<button type="submit" class="btn">Click</button>
```

```
/*
Example test output:

Input: *{2}* mmRRR
Log: true

Input: *{2}* mRRR
Log: false

Input: * mmmRRR
Log: true

Input: * mmRRR
Log: false

Input: mmRRR
Log: No pattern
*/
```

Comment: I entered * {5} * aaaaaBBB'. Your code doesn't return desired output

Comment: yes I did. When I added comments * is disappearing. Try it

Comment: can you please explain else {
      patt = new RegExp(text.charAt(0) + '{3}');
    }

Comment: @dragonfly - answer edited with more explanation that hopefully clears it up.

Comment: the string does't always starts with *. https://jsfiddle.net/82smw9zx/2/

Comment: @dragonfly I think you should probably edit your question or post a separate one with more detail explaining the query parameters you want to be able to handle in your input field. I am guessing from your comment that includes the `**{2}*{3} mmmRRss` input that you are trying to build regex that matches multiple characters in sequence but I am not sure what the number of asterisks in your query signifies, whether or not there is some default regex that should be applied for characters where no count is specified, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to calulate the pattern using a regex:

```
/\*\{(\d+)\}\*/
```

It matches a star, a left Square bracket, followed by one or more digits and ending with a right Square bracket and a star.

How to use:

```
var text = 'mmRRR';
var char = text.charAt(0);
var pattern = '*{2}*';
var counter = /\*\{(\d+)\}\*/.exec(pattern)[1] || '3';
var regex = new RegeExp('^' + char + '\{' + counter + '}$');
var result = text.match(regex);
```